# Can you make a Swift Protocol that forces the view controller to fire specific custom NSNotifications?

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

This is a design pattern question.

I have a 'framework' I'm building, and depending on the current displayed ViewController the framework needs to inject a UIButton into that ViewControllers view.

I don't want the ViewControllers to 'know' explicitly about the 'framework', so I was initially using the delegate pattern but that required a 'over-seer' to ensure that when only specific view controllers were loaded, that they knew about the 'framework'.

However, it occurred to me if I could, via a protocol, ensure that all delete ViewControllers fired off the same two **custom** NSNotifications i.e. subscribeToRequestButton and unsubscribeForButton, then the 'framework' would listen out for those, and upon receiving them, have the view controller object passed to it (via the Notification) so that it can inject the button.

Thereby preventing the view controller from knowing about or having a reference to the 'framework'; it just knows, if it want's that button, to fire those two notifications, and ensure that it implements a method for when that button is touched.

Is this possible or is there a better approach?

The key problems are that

a) I cannot have the View Controllers that need the button know about the framework; as they never have the opportunity to have a reference to is passed to them by some manager class, and

b) The framework doesn't know about the view controllers existence until it receives a notification that is needs to inject a button into something.

EDIT:

I'll just use a singleton pattern with a few public accessor methods for passing data in or querying.

Comment: If I were you, I'd investigate method swizzling. It's an Objective-C feature so since UIViewController inherits from NSObject, you can take advantage of this. You can use swizzling to intercept the view controller lifecycle methods, define new implementations, and even fire the original implementation.

Comment: I know about swizzling, but I have no idea how that could help this design problem.

Comment: Actually I don’t quite see what the difficulty is. You can surely use a protocol to inject a method that posts a notification, and that guarantees the existence of a method for being replied to with another notification. no?

Comment: inject? 

I want the end user of the framework to be forced to fire off custom pre-defined notifications such that the framework picks them up. I don't want the end user to have to poke around and find what the notification prototype needs to be, I wanted that clearly in the protocol, but that doesn't work.